# Cancelled SSL, Google still takes user to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

My problem is on a GoDaddy hosted Wordpress installation. I decided to move the site just a few days after adding SSL, and I left the certificate behind, I no longer want it.  Many users are still seeing my site as `https://example.com` because Google indexed this, or because the site is in their cache.  This is a big problem, because browsers throw up untrusted certificate warnings, and users don't continue on to the site.

I've been trying to solve this problem by:

1. Using Google Webmaster Tools and asking Google to re-crawl/re-index my URLs.
2. Trying to write a 301 redirect into my htaccess file, which would redirect from https to http.

My 301 redirects have not worked yet.  I have read several articles and tried these code snippets:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I'm beginning to doubt that this will work.  Does anyone know if it is possible?

Comment: You are not going to be able to use a rewrite to redirect if they are hitting https first. I would reinstall the cert and then setup a 301 redirect to http and will eventually get indexed as http. That might be the only way you fix this immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, only time healed this wound.  Fortunately Google un-indexed my HTTPS address pretty quickly.